# Allow VMWare client to connect only via VPN

Tags: vmware-esx, openvpn

I have a VMWare (currently using Workstation on Vista, but thinking about switching to ESX) client with Windows XP. I've installed OpenVPN in the client and it connects to the corporate VPN server. I want to make sure that all traffic from the Windows XP machine goes trough this VPN tunnel, but I can't change any settings on the corporate VPN server.

Is it possible to restrict the internet connectivity of the Windows XP client in such a way that it can only send packets to the IP of the corporate VPN server? In that way it'd be impossible for packets to bypass the tunnel. I've looked at NAT configurations but couldn't see how I could make this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a windows box handy, but in advanced TCP/IP settings there is a checkbox that says "Use Default Gateway on Remote Network". This will do what you need.

> Double-click My Computer, and then
>   click the Network and Dial-up
>   Connections link. Right-click the VPN
>   connection that you want to change,
>   and then click Properties. Click the
>   Networking tab, click Internet
>   Protocol (TCP/IP) in the Components
>   checked are used by this connection
>   list, and then click Properties. Click
>   Advanced, and then click the Use
>   default gateway on remote network

Comment: Thanks, but I have to be very sure that no packets escape...

Comment: I don't think packets would "escape", because it will set your Default gateway to the IP address of the remote VPN gateway, so *all* traffic would flow that way.... Now, I am not entirely sure if this would work for a VM, since it will be using your Host computer networking.

Comment: What would happen if the VPN connection gets disconnected? Wouldn't it fall back to the default gateway?

Comment: Yes, it will fall back onto your default gateway, but you can just hard set your default gateway to the VPN gateway. In that case, if you drop the VPN connection, you will not be able to connect to anything else, until you re-establish the VPN connection.